# Images not being transformed to correct dimensions in image carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caroufredsel

When adding an anchor tag around images in an image carousel (using the "[carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/)" 6.2 jQuery library), the images are not correctly transformed to the correct dimensions. When removing the anchor tag, the images are transformed to the correct dimensions and work as expected. The CSS has also been changed so that all styling that was applied to the image is now applied to the anchor tag instead and the problem is still not resolved.

To demonstrate the problem, I have reproduced the problem on JSFiddle along with the expected result in another fiddle. The actual Javascript code used starts at line 19.

[Actual result](http://jsfiddle.net/qFdUx/)

[Expected result](http://jsfiddle.net/wqBGP/1/)

It is worth noting that I have changed this snippet:

```
#carousel img {
display: block;
float: left;
border: none;
position: relative;
}
```

to

```
#carousel a {
display: block;
float: left;
border: none;
position: relative;
}
```

to apply the styling to the anchor tag instead of the image, which is reflected in the code on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you problem is in js its applying css on a instead of img.
partially resolved, unfortunately i dont have enough time right now but you can start from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qFdUx/3/) 
i add `.children()`  to get to img intead of a

Comment: This solution works well, however when the page first loads the images do not animate. Example: http://imgur.com/2DnS8qY

Answer (score 0):

In Actual result jsfiddle, I changed

```
#carousel a, img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        position: relative;
    }
```

to:

```
#carousel a, #carousel img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        border: none;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Is that what your are looking as output, please run and see.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the same for me, are you sure you were viewing the actual result instead of the expected result?

Comment: @Ryan, Yes - I updated #carousel a, img {} to #carousel a, #carousel img {}

Comment: Are you able to create a new JSFiddle with the code in so that I can see? I am unable to reproduce it still.

Comment: you problem is in js its applying css on "a" instead of "img". .children() return you a instead of img that you wont

Comment: @srk This is what happens when I try the suggested code changes. http://jsfiddle.net/p2cAc/